# How to crop a shapefile using a raster with Geotools?

Tags: geotools, geotiff-tiff, clip

I'm working on a project for my school for which I need to use Geotools.
I need to be able to display a raster file and a shapefile, but the shapefile is way bigger than the raster and I just want to display the part in common with the raster.

Would someone know how to "crop" my shapefile and only keep the vectors in a specific area ? With Geotools of course.
I'm using a Tiff with a tfw file as a raster.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao,
I would probably look at the clip process which is part of process-vector.

Examples here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/test/java/org/geotools/process/vector/ClipProcessTest.java)